# Textbox problems with specific characters input

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, textbox, windows-10

I have a Winforms application with some textboxes which uses Microsoft Sans Serif font.

When running my application on Windows 7, everything works as intended.
When I run the application on Windows 10, I can not type OR paste letters 'Ā' (U+0100) and Ē (U+0113) inside the textbox. (Character Ā transforms to A and character Ē transforms to E)

When I open font settings then I see that Microsoft Sans Serif supports both (U+0100) and (U+0113).

Has someone experienced similar issues?

Comment: _" I can not type OR paste letters"_, what do you mean? you can't write those characters or you see strange ones?

Comment: @Ferus7 sorry, forgot to specify (edited post now). Ā transforms to 'A' and Ē transforms to 'E'

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but is working for me. I guess you enabled the hex numpad, btw, Ē =>(U+0112)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is is your font size. Changing the font size of the text box to larger values was enough. I changed it to 12 pt, and it was clearly showing.

```
private void OnForm1_Loading(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",
        12F,
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
        ((byte)(0)));
    // TODO: make a proper font using the original font properties of textBox1
    this.textBox1.Text = "ĀĒ";
}
```

9pt was the smallest font size that showed the tilde. With font size 8pt the tilde was gone.

Comment: This is not the case. I tried to change font size and the tilde still does not appear.